# react dropzone and nodejs file upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using react-dropzone to upload files. From react-dropzone , I am getting a preview which is a blob url.

> Preview: "blob:http://localhost:8080/96ff7bfc-2825-4316-8914-943a1b3b7f28"

How can i access the same in the server side nodejs ? I would want to have a copy of the file in server and return the server path to client.

Answer (score -1):

nodejs code: refer [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/file-upload-form-express-dropzone-js/)

```
var express  =  require( 'express' );
var multer   =  require( 'multer' );
var upload   =  multer( { dest: 'uploads/' } );
var sizeOf   =  require( 'image-size' );
var exphbs   =  require( 'express-handlebars' );
require( 'string.prototype.startswith' );

var app = express();

app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/bower_components' ) );

app.engine( '.hbs', exphbs( { extname: '.hbs' } ) );
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.get( '/', function( req, res, next ){
  return res.render( 'index' );
});

app.post( '/upload', upload.single( 'file' ), function( req, res, next ) {

  if ( !req.file.mimetype.startsWith( 'image/' ) ) {
    return res.status( 422 ).json( {
      error : 'The uploaded file must be an image'
    } );
  }

  var dimensions = sizeOf( req.file.path );

  if ( ( dimensions.width < 640 ) || ( dimensions.height < 480 ) ) {
    return res.status( 422 ).json( {
      error : 'The image must be at least 640 x 480px'
    } );
  }

  return res.status( 200 ).send( req.file );
});

app.listen( 8080, function() {
  console.log( 'Express server listening on port 8080' );
});
```